# Sockets: Receiving data from an (mostly) unknown (bluetooth) device

Tags: sockets, bluetooth

I have a GPS tracker from which I want to collect the location data that it stored somehow. Client software exist, but I want to try it for myself.

I already downloaded and installed the needed python libraries and successfully connected to the device. Now, I have the socket (sending "Hello World" results in "4") and I don't know, what to do next.

How can I receive data from the device? Is it even possible?

[This is the Bluetooth profile the device supports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile#Serial_Port_Profile_.28_SPP_.29)

I would be glad if you could help me.

Best regards,
Jan Oliver

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the protocol of the device, which somtimes is openly published sometimes not.

For example I know that some professional (centimter-precision) GPS devices even have protection by a special handshake procedure that the client software need to send before it will allow any communication, to prevent any third-party software to be written.

If you can specify the exact brand and model of the GPS tracker it will be easier to help.

Comment: I thought that this RS-232 is the protocol... Just serial. The device is called "iGeo" produced by "Networx". The GPS Bluetooth device they use is "BT-Q1300" by QStarz.

Comment: The GPS surely implements some protocol on top of RS-232, which is just a byte-stream. A commonly used protocol is NMEA, google gives some relevant links.

Comment: I figured it out, just used socket.recv(1024) and there is my data. Thanks for the help!